# Can Cloud Functions for Firebase be used to host an entire service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Would it be a good or bad idea to build an entire (production) application service on Cloud Functions for Firebase?  Most of the documentation and demonstrations seem to imply that it should be used more for one-off operations (trigger based events, etc).  What would be the pros & cons for using it as a full-fledged service host?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question.  Consider instead using a site like Quora or the firebase-talk group to start a discussion.